# npx react-native init AwesomeProject Fails

Tags: react-native

Trying to create a new application, following https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Command: **`npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli`**

> up to date, audited 1 package in 235ms 
> found 0 vulnerabilities

Command: C:\Users\Rasel\Desktop\projects> **`npx react-native init AwesomeProject --verbose`**

(I am mentioning only the error part here)

> debug Getting config from C:\Users\Rasel\AppData\Local\Temp\rncli-init-template-FImw31\node_modules\react-native\template.config.js 
> error Error: Couldn't find the "C:\Users\Rasel\AppData\Local\Temp\rncli-init-template-FImw31\node_modules\react-native\template.config.js file inside "react-native" template. 
>  Please make sure the template is valid. Read more: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/init.md#creating-custom-template

After error, the C:\Users\Rasel\AppData\Local\Temp\rncli-init-template-FImw31 folder gets deleted, as it should, I guess. But one observation I feel I should mention is: **C:\Users\Rasel\AppData\Local\Temp\rncli-init-template-FImw31\node_modules folder NEVER GETS CREATED**. I believe this might be the real problem.

My OS is **Windows 11**.
Node Version: 16.18.0

I tried the above commands from CMD and Powershell, with or without Administrator rights, globally installing yarn with npm, or enabling corepack in node, cleaning npm cache, and also with setting Execution Policy 'Unrestricted'/'RemoteSigned'.

Yes, **`npx react-native init AwesomeProject --npm`** works, with the node_modules folder getting created.

But I want it with yarn, without `--npm` flag. What should I do, please?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **C:\Users\Rasel\AppData\Local\Temp\rncli-init-template-FImw31\node_modules folder NEVER GETTING CREATED** is the issue.

My yarn version is 3.2.3 . It was a yarn-related issue.

## Solution

I added an Environmental Variable with name **YARN_NODE_LINKER** and value **node-modules** .

For Explanation:

1. https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-use-yarn-3-with-react-native-and-how-to-migrate-c5f108108533
2. https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration#if-required-enable-the-node-modules-plugin
3. https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc